# Upsert using REST API creates duplicate records?

Tags: rest-api, leads

I am integrating with the Salesforce REST API and am upserting Lead records against an External ID using a Patch method.

For some crazy reason I am seeing duplicate records on the Salesforce side, even though I am making the call only once from my external Java code.  I know that I need to make my external ID enforce unique values, but shouldn't using patch keep this from happening too?

About 10% of my records per day are getting created at least 2 times (and the timestamps are identical).

**Edit**

I just dug through my logs - my external system is getting hit with requests to send back to SF half a second apart - this is creating near-simultaneous calls to SF and the dupe records. I'm going to put some queueing in place on the external system to throttle this.

Comment: Are you sure that the external ids are the same? Are you sure you don't have duplicates being upserted from the external system?

Comment: I am making the api call once per record from my code and the Lead records are completely identical. Could server load cause calls to be fired in parallel?

Comment: Upserts don't create duplicates, though, unless the external ids are different. Are you sure the external ids are the same? Or that duplicates don't already exist?

Comment: I just dug through my logs - my external system is getting hit with requests to send back to SF half a second apart - this is creating near-simultaneous calls to SF and the dupe records.  I'm going to put some queueing in place on the external system to throttle this.

Comment: Don't forget to write that up as the answer!